# Port ASPX page to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, captcha

I'm trying to port an existing ASPX page, which is part of an existing web site, into a new Sharepoint site.  The ASPX page is a relatively simple form with some server-side controls, the ability to email form submissions and "Captcha".  The current website has the Newtonsoft.CaptchaControl dll registered in the bin folder.  So what I need to do is:

1. Port the ASPX page into the proper location within the content of a Sharepoint site
2. Properly register the CaptchaControl dll with Sharepoint and link allow the ASPX page to utilize it

Answer (score 1):

**Set up application page**

The ASPX page would be called an 'application page' in SharePoint. You can copy the ASPX to the `layouts` folder under the "12 Hive". ("%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS"). It would then be accessible from any SharePoint site under `{URL}/_layouts/CustomPage.aspx` (e.g. `http://site/_layouts/CustomPage.aspx` or `http://site/subsite/_layouts/CustomPage.aspx`).

**Add safe control entries**

It looks like you know to place any DLL for your aspx page as well as CaptchaControl.dll in the `bin` folder for the SharePoint site under IIS. The DLLs must be signed with a strong name key. You also need to add the strongly-named signature of the DLLs to the SafeControls list in the `web.config` file for the SharePoint site. If you open up the web.config you'll see examples, e.g.:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

**Configure code access security**

Assuming your controls actually *do* something, you need to mark them as trusted in the Code Access Security file that SharePoint uses. Change the trust level in `web.config` from `WSS_Minimal` to `WSS_Custom`. Go to "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\CONFIG" and copy `wss_minimaltrust.config` to `wss_customtrust.config`. Edit wss_customtrust.config and make new CodeGroup entries using the public key of your DLLs. For example:

```
<CodeGroup
    class="UnionCodeGroup"
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust">
    <IMembershipCondition
        class="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
        version="1"
        PublicKeyBlob="002400000480435694000000060200000024245452534131000400000100453261002888e278243eb86b47eea4be1b23451177126fb9c847085e66e895a64b148c675dabda94d9301f4886a0126887bcd067356affb16a5112baf3198525fc96c45f4178a6263e1a1132bb6c0a4cdaeaccd97b0d4ab42139585700c41e8481feff03e13f30bb0a10ffa7746770d144be94954b7a908fb9bb680ebe611f50f6db" />
</CodeGroup>
```

*Note:* This will make your DLLs fully trusted within the SharePoint web application. It is better practice to restrict permissions to those actually required.